# pcscd and libccid installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I tried to install the pcscd and libccid on Ubuntu 18.04 using apt-get install pcscd libccid. The error is Package pcscd is not available, but is referred to by another package. There may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted or is only available from another source

Can anyone please tell me how to install pcscd and libccid on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: hi tatsu, sorry I lost the dialogue session where I tried to explain all the steps to upgrade 18.04 to 19.04. I will try again here

Comment: step 1: sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade - ok except it suggests to remove libfreetype6

Comment: step2: sudo apt install update-manager-core - ok

Comment: step3: sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades - ok

Comment: step4: sudo sed -i 's/bionic/disco/g' /etc/apt/sources.list - ok

Comment: step 3a (sorry missed this) sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades - ok changed prompt=Normal

Comment: step 5: sudo sed -i 's/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list - error sed: can't read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list: No such file or directory

Comment: this is the first error message, will stop going further from here

Comment: Hi tatsu, sorry I lost our conversation in a separate thread, hope you can still see my post here. I followed the 18.04 to 19.04 upgrade and encountered the problem of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list not found. Would be very grateful for your further advice